# npm run dev is not working in Laravel 7 project

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack

I am working with Laravel 7, installed auth bootstrap and ran `npm install` command as well. After I ran `npm run dev` command the following error messages occurred:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--hide-modules'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
```

How could I fix this problem?
**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack": "^5.23.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json ?

Comment: yes , now you can see my json file

Comment: Just remove the argument

Comment: Laravel updated the `script` sections at some point. The new syntax can be seen [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json). it's also a lot cleaner. Also remove `webpack` from your dependencies. Mix will install the version it needs automatically. Your issue here is you've upgraded mix to a version newer than what L7 came with

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it with below steps:

1. add `"webpack": "^5.23.0"` in package.json
2. run commands:

```
npm uninstall sass
npm uninstall sass-loader
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

after that `npm run dev` worked properly.

Comment: got following error message here 'Remove-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'rf'.
At line:1 char:7'

Comment: @Ranawaka what's your OS?Windows?

Comment: @Ranawaka You can call Remove-Item without -rf, and it still works, but it asks you for confirmation, means run ```rm node_modules```. You can say “A” for “Yes to all” and then it does what You want.

Comment: @Ranawaka you can also able to solve the problem with a downgrade to ```"webpack": "^4.44.1"```. Afterwards ```npm run development``` may work without problems.

Comment: how could I downgrade webpack?

Comment: @Ranawaka change ```"webpack": "^5.23.0"``` to ```"webpack": "^4.44.1"``` in package.json and run ```npm run development```